# No responsive design is displayed

Tags: css, responsive, theme-twenty-thirteen

I have a strange problem. I'm using the Twenty Thirteen theme. When I decrease the navigator width it should make the h1 title decrease too, but it does not. I have the next default css rule:

```
.entry-title, .format-chat .entry-title, .format-image .entry-title, .format-gallery .entry-title, .format-video .entry-title {
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

inside

```
@media (max-width: 643px){ ... }
```

It works fine with other web page that I've done with the same theme, but not with it.
I've tried with different rules, but no luck. When I look at the css code with Firebug, I see the rule, but it is not taken into account in h1 with the .entry-title class. 
Any idea of what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was my fault. I had added a media-query to style.css and I put:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
h2.site-description {
    margin-top: 130px;
}
```

That is to say, I forgot a bracket. It should be:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
h2.site-description {
    margin-top: 130px;
}
}
```

That broke all my next css properties.